# Is ELM327 capable of reading 'Body' codes?

Tags: obd-ii, elm327, bcm

I'd like to be able to read 'body' codes such as the one shown in the enclosed snippet.  In particular, I'm working with a 2014 Chrysler Town & Country.  Do you know if the ELM327 has capability to read them? ...or how/where I might find more info about it's capability?

Thanks,
Eggy

[ELM327]

[Screen snippet of sample 'body' code, B10C43, via controller for heated seats & steering wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIYRV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the *diagnostic trouble codes* (DTCs).

This can simply be done by requesting service `03`

So enter `03` on the ELM327 command prompt.

The car will reply back with the list of stored DTCs.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check that out!